# How to store and retrieve auth token with Apollo + Next.js with SSR?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo-client, react-server-components

Having trouble grasping the idea behind authentication with Apollo Client + Next.js SSR.

If I understand correctly, when using Next.js 13 (with new app router) all components are by default React Server Components.

Meaning if I use Apollo Client - I should have Apollo client for browser and for nodejs (when Next.js renders on server side).

I am using `@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr` package for server side.

So, when I authenticate against my graphql backend, I authenticate on the client side. I recieve token. Naturally I store it in localStorage.
After that all client side requests to server can send token successfully.

But what about server side? How Apollo client for server side can obtain this token? I mean I can't believe that I should like use Redis and simply send another backend request to store token in Redis, so server side Apollo client would get token from there and even if that is the case - how to link current users computer to stored value in redis? It's not browser. It's backend that works on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by storing token with `cookies().set(name, token)`.

Basically if you want to use Apollo Client with authentication in the Client components as well as in the Server components - you will have 2 Apollo client instances (it is by the Apollo client documentation for usage with Next.js 13 with App Router).

So where to store token so 2 Apollo client instances will have access to it?

In the cookies, utilizing Next.js cookies feature.

Basically you will need Route Handler or Server Action in your next.js app.
After obtaining auth token after successful login - redirect to this server action/route handler with token in query parameter.

Now. In your Server Action/Route Handler you simply save token into the cookies.

Like that: `cookies().set("token", YOUR_TOKEN)`

Okay. So what's next?

After all these steps you actually need to get token from cookies.

After another redirect from server action/route handler your app will be remounted again.

In the root layout - read token from cookies (Next.js 13 App router has root layout as server component) and then pass it to wherever you want. Props. Context. Somewhere Next.js shares between client and server components.

Voila!